# Include a plain HTML file and folder with Angular CLI Build?

Tags: angular

Is there a way for me to include a static html file using ng build?
I would like to place it in a sub folder every time I build

e.g.
MySite.com/**static/index.html**

I know I can do that manually, but would prefer to not do that for every build

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `static` folder in your project and with `index.html` in it. Then, just add an entry to the target folder under `assets` in your `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "static" 
      ],
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md), you can do this in `.angular-cli.json`. Add an entry to the `apps` `assets` array, similar to the following:

```
{ "glob": "index.html", "output": "static" }
```

This assumes that `index.html` is in the `src` folder. You can also include an `input` property in the object if the source directory is different.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this via a search for the same issue. The Angular documentation and file structure has changed a bit since previous posts.

Now configure it in `angular.json` and it is documented here:

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration

Comment: explain a bit of what is relevant to question in your answer for a better understanding of viewers.